# How can I resize <input type="text"> element to fit its parent element?

Tags: javascript, css, resize

I want to place the `<input>` element inside `<td>` without the `<td>` element being resized.
These are my CSS codes:

```css
td {
  border: 2px dashed Silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 55px;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
.seatLabel {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

My JavaScript codes:

```js
this.body = document.createElement("td");
```

```js
this.body.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='seatLabel'>"
```

I'm using `this.body` because these two codes are inside the class constructor. 
How can I solve this problem?

> I tried to use *max-width* and *max-height*, but they aren't working.

Comment: post your html code too so that the viewer can try it by themselves and can come up with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give your input `position:relative`, and `width:100%`. So, it will automatically resize to the remaining width in the td element.

Answer (score 1):

please share your html code so can easily understand he problem?
or
Here is a solution

```
<head>
<style>
    table.tg td{
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px dashed Silver;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: darksalmon;
    }
    table.tg input{
       width: 70px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<div >
    <table class="tg">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```